# Why am I obtaining this strange result adding all the values in 2 Excel columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not into Excel and I have this problem trying to sum the values of 2 different column and put this result value into a cell.

So basically I have the **D** column containing 2 values (at the moment only 2 but will grows without a specific limit, I have to sum all the values in this column). These value are decimal values (in my example are: 0,3136322400 and 0,1000000000).

Then I have an **I** column containing the same type of value (at the moment only one but also the values in this column can grow without a specific limit...in my example at this time I have this value −0,335305)

Then I have the **K3** cell where I have to put the sum of all the valus into the **D** column and all the values into the **I** column (following my example it will contain the result of this sum: **0,3136322400 + 0,1000000000    −0,335305**.

Following a tutorial I tried to set this simple forumla in the **K3** cell:

```
=SUM(A:I)
```

The problem is that in this cell now I am not obtaining the expected result (that is **0.07832724**) but I am obtaining this value: **129236,1636322400**.

It is very strange...I think that maybe it can depend by the fact that the **D** and the **I** column doesn't contain only number but both have a textual "heder" (that is the string "QUANTITY" for both the cells). So I think that maybe it is adding also the number conversion of this string (but I am absolutly not sure about this assertion).

So how can I handle this type of situation?

Can I do one of these 2 things:

1) Adding the column values starting from a specific  starting cell in the column (for example: sum all the values under a cell without specify a down limit).

2) Exclude in some way the "header" cells from my sum so the textual values are not considered in my sum.

What could be a smart solution for my problem? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You're summing the range from all columns A through to I. What is in the columns you don't need? Your problem shouldn't be the headers. Why don't you just sum the columns you need i.e. SUM(D:D,I:I)

Comment: `SUM` ignores text but if you have any dates in the referenced cells then they will be added to the sum. In Excel today = 43087 so I reckon you are including 3 current dates in your sum

Answer (score 0):

The sum function can take several arguments.
         `=sum(d2:d10000, i2:I10,000, more columns )`

This should remove the header from the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn your data into an Excel Table (Insert > Table), you can use structured referencing to address a table column, excluding the header.

```
=SUM(Table1[This Header],Table1[That Header])
```

Then you don't need to reference whole columns. If you add new data to the table, the formula will take that into account.

[image]